# Why is my DateTime Formatting wrong, so that the data is not always not being passed back

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a C# MVC Page, and all other data is passed back to the controller correctly, apart from one Date / Time that is set. I am using JQuery DatePicker. the relevant property in the ViewModel is

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Delivery Date")]
    [Display(Name = "Delivery Date", Prompt = "Please Select Delivery Date", Description = "Delivery Date")]
    [UIHint("DateTime")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
```

My Editor for DateTime Controls is;

```
@Html.TextBox("", value, new { @class = "datefield", type = "date", @width= "100px" })
```

And the View Code is

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DeliveryDate, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DeliveryDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DeliveryDate, String.Empty, new { @class = "error" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript is

```
$(function () {

$.validator.addMethod('date',
function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }
    var ok = true;
    try {
        $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
    }
    catch (err) {
        ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
});
$(".datefield").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeYear: true, altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});
```

Looking at the source as the page runs, And the DeliveryDate Field has the correct id and name, so it is bound to the ViewModel. In addition, if I select a date where the day is 12 or less, then the whole thing works, so it must be a formatting issue. But as far as I can see, I have it all set up correctly.

Comment: "The whole thing works" - are you sure you're getting the date you expect?   1/11/2017 is that 1st Nov or 11th Jan in your back-end?  Does the "12" in "the day is 12 or less" mean anything to you?

Comment: The other properties on my model all come back, which is what I meant about the rest of the thing working. But in answer to the second part of your question, no. I selected 3/4/2017 (3rd of April) and in my controller it is showing 4/3/2017 , so it is swapping days and months, no matter that I am asking it to format it in dd/MM/yy format

Comment: Oddly, if I set the return parameter in my View Model to be a string, it works. I can than DateTime.Parse(viewModel.deliveryDate) the string and all is happy. So unless inspiration strikes tonight, Im going to leave it as that.

Answer (score 0):

Add [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) as soon as you have to validate date and to send a well formatted value date to action. 
Another things is `dateFormat` of datepicker is the display of the date and not the format of the value of the component.

**EDIT**

Try with this

```
$(".datefield").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeYear: true, altField: 'DeliveryDate', altFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
```

You do retrieve in your model the parameter DeliveryDate as a Date.

Comment: But how does adding another js library that needs to be explicitly invoked help me here, or explain what is actually going wrong so I can fix it?

Comment: How did you submit ? button submit or ajax call ?

Comment: Whole form is POSTed off a button, no ajax is involved on this page.

Comment: Looks like none of the Date Controllers are working, so its an application wide issue. Only other thing that has recently changed is that the Site was 'Globalised.' I have checked, and my current culture is en-GB, hence the dd-MM-yyyy pattern.

Comment: Yes, you've got a format that is display and a format that is sent. Try the example I have updated above.

Comment: Will try that shortly. However the altField name varies, so if this works, then I'll need to come up with a version that lets me vary that parameter. But Lets prove it works first I guess. I have one example page ion the site that works by Ajax, so Im getting more confused!

Comment: That doesn't work. Intercepting the post shows that the DeliveryDate is being filled. for example it contained 27%2F04%2F2017 so it is coming back from the browser in the correct format. So I assume that the issue appears to be with the .net model binding.

Comment: dd/MM/yyyy is a bad format. In doubt, you do use the universal format yyyy-mm-dd, or use moment.js to cast your value to date in javascript and send it in Action.

Comment: dd/M/yyyy is a pretty standard format across Europe. Though so long as it is displayed in that format, I am happy to work with it in a UTC format behind the scenes. (In fact it would make much more sense to if we want to use this globally). As an experiment I'll strip out all the formatting and see if it works, then go about looking into moment for the ui

Comment: No, you mix display format and sent format. Display format is MM/dd/yyyy (US) or dd/MM/yyyy (EU) or yyyy/MM/dd (JP) or anything format that match the culture. But ASP.NET considers by default that date format is MM/dd/yyyy or ISO (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ). So the easiest way to be sure to sent a good format across the culture is to sent in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. This still isn't working. I am about to update my original question to show where I am now. Debugger shows that the correct date is being sent from the page. So it is still a binding issue.